# Apache Flink - time between events

Tags: events, time, streaming, apache-flink

I am starting to experiment with Apache Flink and have achieved some very basic stuff. Now am I looking forward to finding out the time difference between consecutive elements.

My idea was to use countWindowAll(2) on a stream so that I could evaluate windows with 2 consecutive events. However, I don't understand how I can get access to the timestamps of the 2 events in the window to emit / map this into time difference.

Does someone have a good reference or even some example code for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Do your events have event-time timestamps that you want to compare, or are you wanting to use the CPU clock to measure the interval between processing one event and the next?

Comment: I intend to use event-time timestamps. So far, I am experimenting with the Twitter stream to gather some experience - do the tweet events have event timestamps ?

Comment: Make a window with size 2 and apply the function to get the difference, something looks like this: `text.flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+")).map((_, System.currentTimeMillis())).countWindowAll(2).apply[Long]((_, iter, c) => c.collect(iter.last._2 - iter.head._2)).print()`

Comment: Keep in mind that most applications with event-time timestamps end up processing events that are out-of-order, in which case comparing the timestamps on consecutive events may not be very meaningful.

Comment: BTW, the WikipediaEditEvent objects used in https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html do have timestamps.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the hints. Will try and feedback.